# UE4 creating a new c++ gamemode class

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I am defining a class in a header file. It's inheritence from another class named AGameMode. In the editor i am creating new class from Gamemode and it's auto generates .h and .cpp files. Problem is, i already include the necessary header files still can't see the class i want to inheritence from it. Instead of it throws me error. Let me explain with code:

```
//ACollectorMan_GameMode.h 

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/GameMode.h"
#include "CollectorMan_GameMode.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class MYPROJECT2_API ACollectorMan_GameMode : public AGameMode
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
    ACollectorMan_GameMode();
}
```

when i declare the constructer and compile it shows me error. But if i won't declare it, in the editor line 7(class MYPROJECT2_API ACollectorMan_GameMode : public AGameMode) won't be throw error(still will be red).

This is not only for Gamemode parent class. Character or Pawn classes have same problem. When i build VS gives me that error :

```
CollectorMan_GameMode.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: __cdecl ACollectorMan_GameMode::ACollectorMan_GameMode(void)" (??0ACollectorMan_GameMode@@AEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl ACollectorMan_GameMode::__DefaultConstructor(class FObjectInitializer const &)" (?__DefaultConstructor@ACollectorMan_GameMode@@SAXAEBVFObjectInitializer@@@Z)

CollectorMan_GameMode.gen.cpp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: __cdecl ACollectorMan_GameMode::ACollectorMan_GameMode(void)" (??0ACollectorMan_GameMode@@AEAA@XZ)
```

This should be a linker problem however "GameMode.h" file available at "GameFramework/GameMode.h". I can show you a similiar file. But it's works. There is an example:

```
#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/GameModeBase.h"
#include "MyProject2GameMode.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class AMyProject2GameMode : public AGameModeBase
{
     GENERATED_BODY()
     AMyProject2GameMode(); 
};
```

That all i say.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are a couple of things that need to be addressed, first of all, are you sure you know what the UCLASS() does?? I have never seen that type of class declaration in my 3 years of c++. Also your second include statement, GameFrameWork/GameModeBase.h seems to suggest that you have your header files and cpp files in different folders, do not do this, c++ will not be able to find your header file. So your cpp doesn't know you header file, and hence cannot find the functions declared in your header file.

Comment: UCLASS() using all c++ class header files in the engine. Header and cpp files in same directory. When include a engine header calling it "GameFramework/Header.h". Check this out : [link](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Programming/Tutorials/PlayerInput/index.html)

Comment: `UCLASS` is unreal specific, the second part about `GameFrameWork/GameModeBase.h` makes no sense to me.

Comment: The error is saying that you must implement your constructors, or remove the declarations. If you keep them, they'll also need to be `public`.

Comment: Yep the UCLASS is the problem, generally, you do not rely on C++ default constructors, to intialize your variables, it is a bad practice, So bad that I rarely see it, if you want to rely on default constructors please stick with Java, Overload the class please......

Comment: Also if you need a hint check this part of the first error: DefaultConstructor(class FObjectInitializer const &)

Comment: Wow also this Game FrameWork library reminds me of JS much..... Hmm did not know we had this in C++...

Comment: `UCLASS` is not the problem. It's sometimes true that not providing a constructor is bad practice, but it's not black and white. If it's a class with only default initialized data, or an internal class then it can be fine, or even just if needlessly initializing some data becomes a performance issue. Also, you aren't recognising some of the weird bits of code because they are unreal specific, and backed up by the ubt & uht, they're not strictly standard c++. Anyway, I've downvoted the answer as it comes off more as a collection of comments to me.